# Pre tags as part of JSON response causing Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, express, axios, fetch

> Getting the following error: `index.js:1 Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

It works fine in Postman but it returns the JSON:

```
<pre>{
       "name": "abc123",
       "location": "USA",
       "notes": "qwerty"
}</pre>
```

On the **client**, I am calling this code:

```
try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/search", {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        });
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        console.log(jsonData);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
```

On the server side (express), I have the following code:

```
app.get('/search', function(req, res) {
  let url = `https://myendpoint.com/abcd/search?c=abc123`;

  axios({
      method:'get',
      url
  })
  .then(function (response) {
      res.send(response.data);      
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
});
```

I would've thought by adding `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}` on the client-side would've  solved this issue but not sure if it's the combination of **fetch** and **axios**

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it return `<pre>` string in the json response?

Comment: @hoangdv - no, doesn't return anything just gives the error: `index.js:1 Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` in the console.

Comment: @tonyfat On your server, what happens when you `console.log(response.data)`, or inspect it with a breakpoint?  You're probably getting an error from the upstream system.  Are you sure those `<pre>` tags aren't there?  Because that would explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `<pre>` tag, and convert it to a json object.

On the server-side just response as a json object instead of a string:

```
...
const jsonString = response.data.replace(/<\/?pre>/g, '');
res.json(JSON.parse(jsonString)); // instead of res.send(response.data);
...
```

Comment: With this change, I now get a response but the response still has both the `<pre>{` and `}</pre>` tags attached. How can I remove these pre tags from the response?

Comment: in client as above when I console.log

Comment: All good now - there was an error that I have now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

res.json or res.send json string

```
res.json(result);
res.send(JSON.stringify(result)).end();
```

Comment: This also worked but again, the response still had the pre tags. Would like these removed.

Comment: @lx please consider giving explanation to the OP about cause of the problem they are facing and how your solution mitigates that problem.